# Find last created tar.gz and extract it

Tags: bash, centos, find, extract, xargs

I need to find last created `tar.gz` file and extract it to some directory, something like this:

```
ls -t $(pwd)/Backup_db/ | head -1 | xargs tar xf -C /somedirectory
```

How to do it the right way in CentOS 7?

Comment: Why not `latesttgz=$(ls -1rt "$PWD/Backup_db/"*.tar.gz | tail -n1) ; tar xf -C /somedir "$latesttgz"` ??

Comment: No such file or directory
tar: -C: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Huh? You are supposed to replace `"somedir"` with the directory on your computer you wish to decompress to??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You need to use the archive name after `f` (you used `-C ...` after). That's the error OP is getting.

Comment: @PesaThe - right you are. Watch out for infants Alzheimer's as you get older `:)` (otherwise known as the good old brain-fart...)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the most recently edited file in a subshell, and then use that in place of a filename.  The new directory can be created, and then the tar file can be extracted to it.

```
new_dir="path/to/new/dir"
mkdir -p $new_dir
tar -zxvf $(ls -t *.tar.gz | head -1) -C $new_dir
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer to include some context, appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ls -t <dir>` will not show the full `<dir>/<filename>` path for the files, but `ls -t <dir>/*` will, so after also reordering `xargs` flags (and forcing `-n1` for safety), below should work for you:

```
ls -t $(pwd)/Backup_db/*.tar.gz | head -1 | xargs -n1 tar -C /somedirectory -xf
```